# MVC with Razor: assigning html text

Tags: javascript, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to assign to a javascript variable some html script, but cannot succeed. Here is what I am trying:

```
       var blah = @Html.Raw("Some &lt;strong&gt;text&lt;\/strong&gt;");
```

I cannot even say what the error is, as the result I get looks cryptic:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html.Raw is used to keep a fragment of html from being encoded and displayed as plain text.  You're not using it with actual html, you're using escaped text.  try adding single quotes inside the double quotes:

```
<script>
    var plork = @Html.Raw("'Some <strong>text</strong>'");
    alert(plork);
</script>
```

OR

putting the Html.Raw inside single quotes:

```
<script>
    var plork = '@Html.Raw("Some <strong>text</strong>")';
    alert(plork);
</script>
```

instead